# Multi-story 3d printing

Tags: software, international, search

I'm looking to create a software that assembles multiple small objects into multiple layers. The reason for this is that the objects are relatively small (a few cm diameter), and the printing platform size isn't exactly huge either, but offers a significant height (four of five times the average object). To be able to let the printer run for longer with one job, we'd like to make a relatively big support structure that covers multiple levels of objects.

Is there an existing patent that would shut us down? We're still looking and haven't found anything yet...

Answer (score 2):

This features is available using skeinforge.

"Empty Layers Only
When selected, support material will be only on the empty layers. This is useful when making identical objects in a stack."

http://fabmetheus.crsndoo.com/wiki/index.php/Skeinforge_Raft#Support_Material_Choice